# If X , Y and Z are positive real numbers and a,b and c are rational number then the value of is?

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried to alive this question but end up asking.please help me out
If X , Y and Z are positive real numbers Nd a,b and c are rational number then the value of $1÷1+ x^b-a+x^c-a$ + $ 1÷1+x^a-b+x^c-b$ + $1÷1+x^b-c+x^a-c$ is ?
[image]

Comment: Please describe what you attempted, even if it didn't work.

Comment: Weird question (in the book). Why do $y$ and $z$ have to be positive real numbers, when they don't appear anywhere in the expression we are to evaluate?

Comment: I would advise picking some positive real value for $x$ (e.g., $x=2$) and some rational numbers $a,b,c$ (say, $a=3$, $b=4$, $c=5$) and doing the calculation and seeing whether it comes to anything interesting, and, if it does, then at least you know what you are trying to prove.

Comment: I tried by letting real values for the variable and everytime I got the answer 1 which is correct answer but I want to know is there any other way or method to prove it.

Comment: Trying values can be useful in convincing you it is true, but it can't prove it.  The obvious approach, which I have not tried, is to put them all over a common denominator and see what happens.  Many of the terms are inverses, so there is hope for simplification.

Comment: I got this here $${\frac { \left( {x}^{c}+{x}^{a}+{x}^{b} \right) ^{3}}{{x}^{a}{x}^{c}{x
}^{b}}}
$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner You got it wrong.

Comment: Yes, i see, maybe i have made a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $x>0$ so the denominators are non-zero (don't see any reason why $y$ and $z$ are given as part of the problem) . Now observe that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1+x^{b-a}+x^{c-a}} & = \frac{x^a}{x^a+x^b+x^c}\\
\frac{1}{1+x^{a-b}+x^{c-b}} & = \frac{x^b}{x^a+x^b+x^c}\\
\frac{1}{1+x^{b-c}+x^{a-c}} & = \frac{x^c}{x^a+x^b+x^c}
\end{align*}
Now you add these to get 
$$LHS=\frac{x^a+x^b+x^c}{x^a+x^b+x^c}=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $x$ is positive, and adding, multiplying, dividing and taking powers of positive numbers again give positive numbers (the only operation that can turn positive numbers into negative ones is subtraction, which is only found in the exponents, but negative exponents don't lead to negative results when the base is positive), you can immediately exclude options (1) and (2).

To get rid of the negative terms in the exponents and make the denominator more symmetric, you can expand the first fraction by $x^a$, the second by $x^b$ and the third by $x^c$. After doing this, you get
$$\frac{x^a}{x^a+x^b+x^c} + \frac{x^b}{x^a+x^b+x^c} + \frac{x^c}{x^a+x^b+x^c}$$
which is easily seen to have the value $1$, which is option (3).